# Unable to insert to std map

Tags: c++, c++17, stdmap

I have a std map consisting of int and pointer to a struct. However using the insert function I am unable to add the same. The error message seems bit too tricky for me to get to the bottom.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

typedef struct 
{

}NODE;

int main()
{
    std::map<int, NODE*> mp;
    int i = 0;
    mp.insert(i, new NODE());

    return 0;
}
```

The error language is bit cryptic. I am trying to add an int and a NODE pointer to map of int and NODE pointer. Why is this giving me un-matching function?

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:22:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map::insert(int&, NODE*)’
     mp.insert(i, new NODE());
                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/map:61:0,
                 from main.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:621:7: note: candidate: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert_return_type std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::node_type&&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = NODE*; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert_return_type = std::_Node_insert_return >, std::_Node_handle, std::allocator > > > >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::node_type = std::_Node_handle, std::allocator > > >]
       insert(node_type&& __nh)
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:621:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:626:7: note: candidate: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::node_type&&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = NODE*; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::node_type = std::_Node_handle, std::allocator > > >]
       insert(const_iterator __hint, node_type&& __nh)
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:626:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘std::map::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >}’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:795:7: note: candidate: std::pair, std::_Select1st >, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::rebind >::other>::iterator, bool> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const value_type&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = NODE*; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >; typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair, std::_Select1st >, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::rebind >::other>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = std::pair]
       insert(const value_type& __x)
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:795:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:802:7: note: candidate: std::pair, std::_Select1st >, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::rebind >::other>::iterator, bool> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = NODE*; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >; typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair, std::_Select1st >, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::rebind >::other>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = std::pair]
       insert(value_type&& __x)
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:802:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:808:2: note: candidate: template std::__enable_if_t, _Pair>::value, std::pair, std::_Select1st >, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::rebind >::other>::iterator, bool> > std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(_Pair&&) [with _Pair = _Pair; _Key = int; _Tp = NODE*; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >]
  insert(_Pair&& __x)
  ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:808:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:22:28: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
     mp.insert(i, new NODE());
                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/map:61:0,
                 from main.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:822:7: note: candidate: void std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::initializer_list >) [with _Key = int; _Tp = NODE*; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >]
       insert(std::initializer_list<value_type> __list)
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:822:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:852:7: note: candidate: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, const value_type&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = NODE*; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = std::pair]
       insert(const_iterator __position, const value_type& __x)
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:852:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘std::map::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >}’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:862:7: note: candidate: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = NODE*; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = std::pair]
       insert(const_iterator __position, value_type&& __x)
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:862:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘std::map::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >}’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:867:2: note: candidate: template std::__enable_if_t, _Pair>::value, typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair, std::_Select1st >, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::rebind >::other>::iterator> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, _Pair&&) [with _Pair = _Pair; _Key = int; _Tp = NODE*; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >]
  insert(const_iterator __position, _Pair&& __x)
  ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:867:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:22:28: note:   cannot convert ‘i’ (type ‘int’) to type ‘std::map::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >}’
     mp.insert(i, new NODE());
                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/map:61:0,
                 from main.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:885:2: note: candidate: template void std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = _InputIterator; _Key = int; _Tp = NODE*; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >]
  insert(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)
  ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:885:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:22:28: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_InputIterator’ (‘int’ and ‘NODE*’)
     mp.insert(i, new NODE());
```

Comment: mp[i]=new Node();

Comment: or `mp.insert({i, new NODE()});`

Comment: there is no overload of `insert` for the arguments you pass, see here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert

Comment: Please read the given link. You simply try to use an interface which did not exist. So you have to pass the correct arguments to the existing interface. `insert` can be called with a `std::pair` but not with two individual parms. `{}` arround the args are implicit converted to std::pair in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aah OK.

So insert function expects a pair.

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:802:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:808:2: note: candidate: template std::__enable_if_t, _Pair>::value, std::pair, std::_Select1st >, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::rebind >::other>::iterator, bool> > std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(_Pair&&) [with _Pair = _Pair; _Key = int; _Tp = NODE*; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >]
  insert(_Pair&& __x)
```

Thanks for the suggestions above.

```
  mp.insert(std::make_pair(i, p));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C++11 or later (which is the case, by default, in recent compiler), then you could use the [`map::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) method instead. With emplace, you can simply pass the two arguments which make up both parts of the pair, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<int, std::string> m;
    m.emplace(123, "ddd");
    for (const auto &p : m) {
        std::cout << p.first << " => " << p.second << '\n';
    }
}
```

See this [running on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/yty4Ss).

Notes:

- I've replaced `NODE` with `std::string` in my example so that you can see it printing.
- If you're using C++17 or later, you might prefer [`map::try_emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace) instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to insert it into the map, you have to insert it as `std::pair` like this:

```
mp.insert(std::pair<int, NODE*>(i, new NODE()));
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes me wonder what stops the compiler from doing the obvious i.e see if the inputs make a valid pair or not.

Comment: @J.Snow: Because overload resolution is complicated enough as it is, and the compiler being too clever by half would not be an improvement.  (It might make sense for the compiler to try to guess what function you meant to call when producing an error message anyway, but that’s pretty difficult anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert an element in a `std::map` you can use the method `emplace` ( https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/emplace/ ) passing the `std::make_pair` constructor parameters directly to it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

typedef struct 
{
}NODE;


int main()
{
    std::map<int, NODE*> mp;
    int i = 0;
    mp.emplace(i, new NODE());

    return 0;
}
```